# How make search in listview (fragment android)?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

How make search in `ListView`?

```
listView.setFilterText(newText);
```

not work.

Any ideas to fix this?

I have `ListView` in with one I add some files. I want make search in this files and show users file.

**You can look at screenshot :**

[image]

**FragmentFolder.java :**

```
public class FragmentFolder extends Fragment{

    static Context context;
    public static Fragment fragment;
    ListView listView;
    private File currentFolder;
    private FileArrayAdapter fileArrayListAdapter;
    private FileFilter fileFilter;
    private File fileSelected;
    private ArrayList<String> extensions;
    SharedPreferences sPref;
    boolean checker;
    Bitmap bmThumbnail;
    ImageView img;
    String path;
    boolean good = false;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_foler, container, false);
        context = v.getContext();
        fragment = this;
//TODO: ЧТОБЫ БЫЛО ВИДНО ПОИСК - УБЕРИ КОММЕНТАРИИ
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("com.fug.video.player", MODE_PRIVATE);
        checker = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("filefilter", true);

        listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                FileInfo fileDescriptor = fileArrayListAdapter.getItem(position);
                if (fileDescriptor.isFolder() || fileDescriptor.isParent()) {
                    currentFolder = new File(fileDescriptor.getPath());
                    fill(currentFolder);
                } else {
                    /** Нужно проверить на расширение файла */
                    fileSelected = new File(fileDescriptor.getPath());
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, PlayerActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("DATA", fileSelected.getAbsolutePath());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                    Log.i("FILE CHOOSER", "result ok");
                }
                }
        });

        currentFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath());
        fill(currentFolder);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        if(null!=searchManager ) {
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        }
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                //listView.setFilterText(query.toString());
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //Поиск realtime
                listView.setFilterText(newText);
                return true;
            }

        });
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    private void fill(File f) {
        File[] folders = null;
        if (fileFilter != null)
            folders = f.listFiles(fileFilter);
        else
            folders = f.listFiles();

        //this.setTitle(getString(R.string.currentDir) + ": " + f.getName());
        List<FileInfo> dirs = new ArrayList<FileInfo>();
        List<FileInfo> files = new ArrayList<FileInfo>();
        try {
            for (File file : folders) {
                if (file.isDirectory() && !file.isHidden())
                    //si es un directorio en el data se ponemos la contante folder
                    dirs.add(new FileInfo(file.getName(),
                            Constants.FOLDER, file.getAbsolutePath(),
                            true, false));
                else {

                    if (!file.isHidden() ) {
                        if ( file.getName().endsWith(Constants.MP4) ||file.getName().endsWith(Constants.MOV) ||file.getName().endsWith(Constants.M4V) ||file.getName().endsWith(Constants.FLV) || file.getName().endsWith(Constants.AVI) || file.getName().endsWith(Constants.GPP3) || file.getName().endsWith(Constants.WEBM) || file.getName().endsWith(Constants.MAT)) {
                           // bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(file.getPath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
                            path = file.getPath();

                            files.add(new FileInfo(file.getName(),
                                    getString(R.string.fileSize) + ": "
                                            + file.length(),
                                    file.getAbsolutePath(),  false, false));
//                                    good = true;
                            //img.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);


//                            Glide.with(context)
//                                .load(file)
//                                .into(img);
                        }
                    }
//                    else {
//                        //Showall files
//                        files.add(new FileInfo(file.getName(),
//                                getString(R.string.fileSize) + ": "
//                                        + file.length(),
//                                file.getAbsolutePath(), false, false));
//                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Collections.sort(dirs);
        Collections.sort(files);
        dirs.addAll(files);
        if (!f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getName())) {
            if (f.getParentFile() != null)
                //si es un directorio padre en el data se ponemos la contante adeacuada
                dirs.add(0, new FileInfo("..",
                        Constants.PARENT_FOLDER, f.getParent(),
                        false, true));
        }

        fileArrayListAdapter = new FileArrayAdapter(context,
                R.layout.file_row, dirs);
        listView.setAdapter(fileArrayListAdapter);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want a full on file search?

Comment: So what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code, This will work for you.

> This is the function  which I write for you, you have to call this function and pass file path to it ... then it will search the name of file with desired searching word and return the list of files array which have the those names.

```
 public void walkdir(File dir) {
    String sPattern = "searching_word";

    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();

    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                walkdir(listFile[i]);
            } else {
              if (listFile[i].getName().startsWith(sPattern)){

                 //Display that file in list

              }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

To search on the whole sdcard call this function using

```
walkdir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
```

Comment: Where wite this code: walkdir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());?

And what write on //Display that file in list?
Help pls, I cannot understand

Comment: @Simon this is the function  which I write for you, you have to call this function and pass file path to it ... then it will search the name of file with desired searching word and return the list of files array which have the those names.

Comment: `walkdir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());` this code means you are passing the root dir path to the function and in code block `//Display that file in list` you have to write the logic yourself for adding those file array to ListView and displaying them.